# org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

Im trying to filter list collection in xml configuration file by SpEL

this is my class

```
public class PCCollection implements MarketPC {

private Collection<PersonalComputer> pcCollection;

public PCCollection(Collection<PersonalComputer> pcCollection) {
    this.pcCollection = pcCollection;
}   ...
}
```

this is bean for this class and fill collection

```
 <bean id="marketPC" class="PCCollection">
    <constructor-arg name="pcCollection">
        <list>
            <ref bean="customPC"/>
            <bean class="MyCustomPC" scope="prototype">
            <constructor-arg name="mother" ref="msiMother"/>
            <constructor-arg name="processor" ref="asusProcessor"/>
            <constructor-arg name="storage" ref="gigabyteStorage"/>
            <constructor-arg name="ram" ref="gigabyteRam"/>
            <constructor-arg name="video" ref="asusVideo"/>
            </bean>
      </list>
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and customPC class

```
public class MyCustomPC implements PersonalComputer {

private MotherBoard mother;
private Processor processor;
private Ram ram;
private StorageDevice storage;
private VideoCard video;
....}
```

when i trying to create bean with expression for filtering my 1st bean

```
 <bean id="marketPCASUS" class="PCCollection">
    <constructor-arg name="pcCollection"
    value = "#{marketPC.pcCollection.?[video eq 'asusVideo']}">
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

i'm receiving exception

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'pcCollection' cannot be found on object of type 'PCCollection' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

what is wrong with that? i tried to google it, but all answers with using annotations, but before it i want to understand how to work in configuration files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> maybe not public or not valid?

you should create a get method for `pcCollection` named `getPcCollection`

Comment: my interface `public interface MarketPC {
    Collection<PersonalComputer> getPCCollection();
}`
says this method is never used, but i have implementation in my class
     `@Override
    public Collection<PersonalComputer> getPCCollection() {
        return pcCollection;
    }`

Comment: @YegorSaliev getPCCollection would be regard as pCCollection.it should be named as getPcCollection

Comment: it works now. but i have another problem:
'<bean id="marketPCASUS" class="PCCollection">
        <constructor-arg name="pcCollection"
        value = "#{marketPC.pcCollection.?[video.toUpperCase eq 'ASUSVIDEO']}">
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>'. now i have this exception `Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'toUpperCase' cannot be found on object of type 'MSI.MSIVideo' - maybe not public or not valid?`. i wanted to show only pc's with asus in video field. what expression should i use?

Comment: oh sorry! im trying to equial string with object! that's my problem